# Web framework based on servlet 3.0

Tags: java, web-frameworks

I was curious to know if anyone's aware whether any of the main web framework teams are working on incorporating the `Servlet 3.0` specs into their stacks? 
AFAIK, they're all based on the 2.5 specs as of now. I think the 3.0 specs brings a lot of nice features in terms of ease of configuration and asynchronous request handling. I was especially interested in the *server push* capabilities.

any information about this?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can take a look at Spring 3.1 documentation :

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#d0e1428

(Currently in Milestone 2).

Comment: I'm not sure if it's entirely based on Servlet 3.0 - they're just working on *incorporating* some of the features. Why I believe it's not based on Servlet 3.0 -> `DispatcherServlet` still requires an entry in `web.xml`, and, there's no mention of `asynchrnous request processing` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Grails 2.0 is based on Servlet 3.0. Check out this [link](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.0.M2/guide/theWebLayer.html#asynchronousRequestProcessing) for asynchronous processing

For server push, it will be much easier to use something like Atmosphere than raw servlet 3.0 Api. Check out [this](http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2009/11/06/servlet-3-0-asynchronous-api-or-atmosphere-easy-decision/) for more detail.